# What are the advantages of using resource over resources in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In rails routes what are the advantages of using

```
resources :user
resource :user
```

I have gone through Google and found that resource will not provide index method. Please post the differences if any.

Comment: Ref `2.2 CRUD, Verbs, and Actions` & `2.5 Singular Resources` from Rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: i tried but i didn't get the exact details.

Answer (score 1):

From Rails guides:

> Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without referencing an ID. For example, you would like /profile to always show the profile of the currently logged in user. In this case, you can use a singular resource to map /profile (rather than /profile/:id)

This is why the `resource` will not provide index route, the purpose is map a single resource.

[Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

Comment: You would need to be aware that `form_for` has a bug that won't work with a singular resource so you need to pass the url explicitly - details on that in the guides as linked to by Rodrigo.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, the intent of resource is to declare that only one of these resources will ever exist. For example:

```
resource :profile, :only => [:edit, :update]
```

As a user, I should only be able to update my own profile. I should never be able to edit other users' profiles, so there's no need for a URL scheme like /users/1/profile/edit. Instead, I use /profile/edit, and the controller knows to use the current user's ID rather than the ID passed in the URL (since there is none).

That's why you don't get an index action with resource: there's only one resource, so there's no sense in "listing" them.